# Definite article "the": (the) benefits of reading books

Tags: grammar, definite-article

I am not sure if there is a difference between using "the" or not in these sentences below:

*Situation 1: At a talk show, I start my speech :

(1) Hi everybody, today, I am going to talk about **(the)** benefits of reading books.

*Situation 2:  I ask one of my friends:

(2) Jim, do you know **(the)** benefits of reading books? I think you should read more books.

*Situation 3: I make a general statement:

(3) **(The)** benefits of reading books are obvious. A lot of people nowadays spend more time on reading books.

*Situation 4: I ask my friend:

(4) Hey, What is **(the)** benefits of reading? Why should I read more?

*Situation 5: I start an paragraph:

Here are **(the)** benefits of reading:

a.Reading Increases General Knowledge.

b.Reading Reduces Stress.

c.....

Im not sure if "the" is optional in my sentences, and what is the difference between them. My instinct says that I should use "the" in situations above.But I just don't know why.

Answer (score -2):

Omitting "the" is entirely appropriate in these sentences. It would be needed if there were specific books under discussion, such as the material for a university course, but you are talking up reading in general.

Comment: These sentences have the same meaning, even with or without "the". Right?

Comment: I don't agree. To me, the sentences sound odd without the article, and imply 'only _some_ of the possible benefits'. (4) should read "What _are_ the benefits...?"